# MySQL JOIN LIMIT DYNAMIC QUERY OPTIMIZATION

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

Here the schema : -

```
Student_Details
ID | Student_id | Name          | Value
1  | 2          | City          | NewYork
2  | 2          | Height        | 5'11'
3  | 2          | Class         | B
4  | 2          | RollNo        | 265454
5  | 2          | Credit        | 800
6  | 3          | City          | Manila
7  | 3          | Height        | 5'10'
8  | 3          | Type          | International
9  | 3          | RollNo        | 2653
10 | 1          | Address       | Main Street
11 | 1          | Height        | 5'9'
12 | 1          | TST           | 21.54
13 | 1          | CCA           | 242
13 | 1          | SEX           | Male

Students 
ID | Name   | Age | AddedOn
1  | Alpha  | 27  | 20 Jan 2019
2  | Beta   | 15  | 19 Jan 2019
3  | Gamma  | 18  | 20 Jan 2019 

Student_Dep_Map
ID |DEP_ID | Student_id
 1 | 4 | 2
 2 | 2 | 1

Department 
ID| Name 
1 | Science
2 | Physics
3 | Chemistry 
4 | Psychology
```

So Search revolves around Students , we need  to search Students with various search criteria such as 'City' ,'Height' Or 'TST' ,Student in which Departments , Added On , Age ,etc.., basically all these tables.
A dynamic search . Also output search should also contains some of the Fixed details from each tables. So I made this query with pivot.

```
select distinct s.*
FROM  students s
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT s.ID as s_id, group_concat(distinct d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as ASSIGNED_DEPT FROM students s   
          JOIN  Student_Dep_Map sdp JOIN  Department d on sdp.DEP_ID = d.ID ON sdp.Student_id=s.id  GROUP BY s.id  ) aa  ON aa.s_id = s.ID 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT  student_id, 
            MAX(if(Name = 'TST', value, null)) as TST,   
                        MAX(if(Name = 'Height', value, null)) as HEIGHT, 
            MAX(if(Name = 'CITY', value, null)) as CITY, 
            MAX(if(Name = 'SEX',  value, null)) as SEX,
            MAX(if(Name = 'RollNo',  value, null)) as ROLLNO 
            FROM student_detials tip  GROUP BY  student_id ) sd ON sd.student_id = s.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND SD.SEX = 'Male' LIMIT 0,100 ;
```

AND criteria is added dynamically through query builder.

Challenge is ! This Query is too slow, as records in tables increased , query became slow drastically . I did use explain to understand the query plan . if I leave indexing & just talk about optimizing query plan.
I noticed when I used pivot even though the search criteria is from main table student still query plan goes through almost all records while pivoting in student details. 
is there any way I can limit joins until 100 records of Students records are found. 
One way is to write sub query for each table to LIMIT results but is there any better approach handle this ? 
I need to Limit joins not just results after joins , so Query results in faster fetch.

Note : Sorry I cannot post real tables , its just mock data.

Comment: Thanks for the responses . Wanted add Few more points . As I said Search is dynamic , search criteria could be belong to student table too or department , like how many student belong to Physics dept Or how many students have age less than 27 , etc.

Comment: I cannot add these 'Sex' ,'Height' columns to a the student details as , This is small sample data , real problem has more 200 unique  name value . pair that defines the student, could be totally unique to a student or maybe a field which is present in every student . Whatever attributes are fix we tried to add in student table . Extra attributes go in student details.Thanks

Comment: Also , Output result could have fix result set , such as all s.* and some student_Details pivot attributes , assigned dept .

Comment: Read about EAV schema.  Your variant of it is quite clumsy and inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `exists` instead of aggregating:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.name SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM Student_Dep_Map sdp JOIN
             Department d 
             ON sdp.DEP_ID = d.ID 
        WHERE sdp.Student_id = s.id
       ) as ASSIGNED_DEPT
FROM students s 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM student_details sd
              WHERE sd.student_id = s.id AND
                    sd.Name = 'SEX' AND
                    sd.Value = 'Male'
             )
LIMIT 0, 100 ;
```

For performance, you want indexes on:

- `Student_Dep_Map(student_id, dep_id)`
- `Departments(id, name)`  (probably exists because `id` should be the primary key)
- `student_details(student_id, name, value)`.

To add more conditions, add more `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: Should the ```student_details``` table be pivotted for design? It seems like all of the variables describe that particular student. That is, should the design be ```ID, Student_ID, City, Height, Class, RollNo, Credit, TST, CCA, SEX, ...```

Comment: @Cole . . . . Sounds expensive in your case.  I don't think you want to take the performance hit.  There is a big difference between returning values for all students -- where `group by` makes sense -- and using the values for filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I meant should the table be fundamentally be redesigned? Understood that it's an expensive operation to pivot for every query.

Comment: @Cole . . . If you know what columns are in the table, you should probably use a single row for each columns.  An EAV approach is not the best approach -- the types may not be correct and you cannot declare foreign key relationships.

Comment: Thanks its really helpful to see the query in a different way . But How should I define a query when search criteria is from student table ?. I added few more comments in my original post.

Comment: @drtvhood . . . You would add `where` conditions based on the `students` table.

Comment: Hi , How should I show other students details for matched records in your query  ? Like TST , CCA etc . Pivot is costly .

Answer (score 0):

Another potential route if you are interested in selecting some of the fields from `student_details`.

```
SELECT s.*

FROM students s

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT student_id 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'TST', value, null)) as TST   
    , MAX(if(Name = 'Height', value, null)) as HEIGHT 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'CITY', value, null)) as CITY 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'SEX',  value, null)) as SEX
    , MAX(if(Name = 'RollNo',  value, null)) as ROLLNO 

    FROM student_details tip  

    GROUP BY  student_id
  ) sd
  ON s.ID = sd.student_ID
   AND sd.SEX = 'Male'

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT sdp.ID as s_id
    , group_concat(d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as ASSIGNED_DEPT

    FROM Student_Dep_Map sdp
    INNER JOIN Department d ON sdp.DEP_ID = d.ID

    GROUP BY sdp.id
  ) aa
  ON aa.s_id = s.ID
;
```

Your original query also had `LEFT JOIN(...) WHERE sd.sex = 'Male'` which would eliminate the the whole `LEFT JOIN` portion. You could potentially simplify it with:

```
SELECT s.ID
, s.Name
, s.Age
, s.AddedOn
, group_concat(d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as ASSIGNED_DEPT
, sd.City

FROM students s
INNER JOIN student_dep_map sdp  ON s.ID = sdp.ID
INNER JOIN Department d     ON sdp.DEP_ID = d.ID
INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT student_id 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'TST', value, null)) as TST   
    , MAX(if(Name = 'Height', value, null)) as HEIGHT 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'CITY', value, null)) as CITY 
    , MAX(if(Name = 'SEX',  value, null)) as SEX
    , MAX(if(Name = 'RollNo',  value, null)) as ROLLNO 

    FROM student_details tip  

    GROUP BY  student_id
  ) sd
  ON s.ID = sd.student_ID

WHERE sd.SEX = 'Male'

GROUP BY s.ID
, s.Name
, s.Age
, s.AddedOn
, sd.City;
```